# MonoDroid, SQLite and LINQ

Tags: linq, sqlite, xamarin.android

I can't seem to find an example of using LINQ over SQLite on MonoDroid.  Is there one available anywhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library works well with Mono for Android and provides some LINQ support. I have a post [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-a-database-in-monodroid-applications/) describing how to use it in Mono for Android applications.